# mapping random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $x$ be a random variable (RV), $a<x<b$ with a pdf $f(x)$. Let's construct a function on $x$, $y=h(x)$ which is continuous and differentiable.

If an inverse function exists for $h$, say $g(y)=x$. Then it says,

$$f(h(x)) = f(g(y)) \left| \frac{dg(y)}{dy} \right|$$

I understand the mapping through $g(y)$. But how does the $\left| \frac{dg(y)}{dy} \right|$ come into play here? Why do I need the derivative? Perhaps a proof would help but is there a geometric intuition?

Comment: Proof is here, page 22. Maybe someone else can be bothered to type it out. http://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/foswiki/pub/Main/NGK/3F1RandProcSV.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to understand it is that if $y=h(x)$ is a strictly increasing continuous and differentiable function then $g(y)=h^{-1}(y)$ is too

then $\displaystyle \Pr(Y \le y)=\Pr(X \le g(y))=\int_a^{g(y)} f(x)\,dx$

and if you now take the derivative of that with respect to $y$, you get $f(g(y))\dfrac{dg(y)}{dy}$

though your original question is marginally more complicated than this.

Comment: I guess the marginal complexity is due to missing the constraint of strictly increasing? What happens in the case my function is non monotonic? Should i just break it down into intervals?

Comment: If it is non-monotonic you have the issue that the inverse may be multi-valued: if $h(x_1)=h(x_2)=k$ then what is $g(k)$? This is what leads to the sum in the [link](http://www-sigproc.eng.cam.ac.uk/foswiki/pub/Main/NGK/3F1RandProcSV.pdf) from texasflood. You could also have the issue that $g'(y)$ could be infinite for some $y$.

Answer (score 0):

This method is easiest understand if $h$ is also monotone increasing on $(a,b)$.
Consider $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ so the $f_X(x) = 1$, for $0 <x<1,$ and 0 otherwise.
Also, let $Y = h(X) = X^2.$ Then 
$$P\{0 < X < .1\} = P\{0 < Y < .01\} = 1/10$$
and
$$P\{.9 < X < 1\} = P\{.81 < Y < 1\} = 1/10.$$
Notice that the intervals for $X$ are of equal width, while the intervals
for $Y$ are of very different widths. So it is already clear that the density function $f_Y$ has to be much "taller" above $(0, .01)$ than it is above $(.80,1)$ for these probabilities to hold.

It turns out that $f_Y(y) = 0.5y^{-0.5},$ for $0 < y < 1,$ and 0 otherwise.
This density function $f_Y$ goes asymptotically to infinity near 0, and is about
1/2 near 1.

I have chosen this example because, in this case, the original density function is a constant over its support $(0, 1)$, the *entire* form of the density of $f_Y$ is due to $dh^{-1}/dy = dx/dy.$ 
(Because the transformation is monotonically *increasing*, no absolute
value signs are needed.) Intuitively, the derivative can be considered
as answering the question, "What adjustment needs to be made in going from $f_X$ above interval $\Delta x$ so that $f_Y$ accommodates to the change
in the length $\Delta y$ to keep the amount of probability the same for the two tiny intervals?"

Note: In this example $X \sim Beta(1,1) = Unif(0,1)$ and $Y \sim Beta(.5,1).$